# docker manifest create annotate and push in a script

Tags: docker, docker-registry, multiarch

I have DockerHub build images for `x86_64` for my projects.  The images have this naming: `myname/project:version_architecture`; such as `foo/bar:1.0.0_x86_64`.

Then I build `aarch64` images on a RPi4: `foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64`, which I then push to DockerHub.

Now I want a manifest that contains both of them so that I can use `foo/bar:1.0.0` anywhere and it will work.

AFAIK, The following commands should work (to be run on the RPi):

```
docker build -t foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64 .
docker push foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64

docker manifest create foo/bar:1.0.0 foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64
docker manifest annotate foo/bar:1.0.0 foo/bar:1.0.0_x86_64
docker manifest push foo/bar:1.0.0
```

But for some reason, the `annotate` step sometimes fails:

```
manifest for image foo/bar:1.0.0_x86_64 does not exist in foo/bar:1.0.0
```

And the following workaround (usually) works instead:

```
docker build -t foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64 .
docker push foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64

docker manifest create foo/bar:1.0.0 foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64
docker manifest annotate foo/bar:1.0.0 foo/bar:1.0.0_x86_64
docker manifest create foo/bar:1.0.0 foo/bar:1.0.0_x86_64 --amend
docker manifest annotate foo/bar:1.0.0 foo/bar:1.0.0_aarch64
docker manifest push foo/bar:1.0.0
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create multiarch manifest you need to build 2 images with different arch

```
export ARCH=i386
docker build -t foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}" --build-arg ARCH=${ARCH} --network=host .
docker tag "foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}" "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}"
docker push "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}"
```

After that you add another image (built from another architecture):

```
export ARCH=arm64v8
docker build -t foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}" --build-arg ARCH=${ARCH} --network=host .
docker tag "foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}" "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}"
docker push "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-${ARCH}"
```

Then you can create a root manifest, add links to actual images and edit it if you need to:

```
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
docker manifest create "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0" \
    --amend  "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-i386" \
    --amend "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-arm64v8"
docker manifest annotate --arch amd64 "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0" "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0-i386"
docker manifest inspect "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0"
docker manifest push "${REGISTRY}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:1.0.0"
```

This allows you to have root manifest with a links to arch-manifests. I used annotate to update image architecture to match exact node type.

Comment: @dtc How skopeo can help in this case?

Based on https://github.com/containers/skopeo/issues/1136 it seems that right now skopeo is not able to craft multiarch docker image from two separate (arch-specific) docker images

Comment: oops, you're right. my comment is irrelevant. I was actually searching for a solution to migrate existing multi-arch images from docker hub to other registries like GCR instead and was frustrated that docker didn't have a solution.

Comment: missing the annotation for arm64 architecture? is that on purpose?